# mod_wsgi is problematic with Django and venv. Can't be loaded as python module. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to setup Django project with Apache and mod_wsgi and couldn't get it to work. Searched all answers, but nothing helped.

- `python-home=/var/www/example.com/venv`
- `python-path=/var/www/example.com/myproject`
- Location of `wsgi.py` - `/var/www/example.com/myproject/myproject/`

**Here is my apache config.**

```
Protocols h2 http/1.1
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIDaemonProcess example python-home=/var/www/example.com/venv python-path=/var/www/example.com/myproject

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin riden@example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/myproject/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/example.com/myproject/static/images/favicon/favicon.ico
    Alias /static /var/www/example.com/myproject/static
    
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIProcessGroup example
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example.com/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**Here is the error.**

```
[28] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 959] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1g mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[53] [core:notice] [pid 959] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[03] [wsgi:error] [pid 969] [remote 1.2.3.4:58356] mod_wsgi (pid=969): Target WSGI script '/var/www/example.com/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[08] [wsgi:error] [pid 969] [remote 1.2.3.4:58356] mod_wsgi (pid=969): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/example.com/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
[32] [wsgi:error] [pid 969] [remote 1.2.3.4:58356] Traceback (most recent call last):
[79] [wsgi:error] [pid 969] [remote 1.2.3.4:58356]   File "/var/www/example.com/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[87] [wsgi:error] [pid 969] [remote 1.2.3.4:58356]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[04] [wsgi:error] [pid 969] [remote 1.2.3.4:58356] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

**Checklist of things I tried,**

- Verified mod_wsgi is compiled for py3 by using `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`. There are no other mod_wsgi in the system (ubuntu 18).
- venv is created with python 3 (3.9) and all the modules are installed from the `myproject/requirements.txt`.
- Activated `venv` and verified Django was working by doing migrations.

What am I doing wrong? I have been trying this since morning and I am out of options. Please help.

**Additional information:**

- My ubuntu has 3 python versions. The default Python 2, Python 3.6, and Python 3.9 (which I created `venv` with).

Comment: is django in requirements.txt also what does pip freeze return

Comment: Yes. It does have Django.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/